# Обобщённый компаратор для Array.Sort()

Tags: c#

Есть компаратор для сортирования в обратном порядке.

```
class Comp<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return -x.CompareTo(y);
        //return  y - x;
    }
}
```

Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтоб можно было возвращать y - x в качестве результата сравнения, как в закомментированном участке(это мешает сделать обобщённый тип Т)

Comment: думаю, что нет. А вообще зачем?

Comment: @DreamChild интерес.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. Операторы не могут использоваться с generic-типами, поскольку они статические и на них нельзя наложить ограничение даже при помощи интерфейса.

Что касается вычитания для сравнения, да и унарного минуса - могут быть проблемы из-за переполнения. Хотя, стандартный Enumerable.OrderByDescending уже содержит этот баг: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/03/02/backward-compatibility-pain/

PS: На самом деле, способ с вычитанием можно упихать, заставив определять типы и искать оператор во время исполнения метода, но это будет очень большим ударом по производительности, особенно с учётом того, что компараторы обычно используются при сортировке.

А самый хороший способ сделать обратный компаратор - это

```
public int Compare(T x, T y)
{
  return y.CompareTo(x);
}
```

Comment: О! Ваш код лучше.

Comment: @VladD, только он не совсем мой - см. пост по ссылке :)

Answer (score 2):

Такой возможности не существует потому, что на текущий момент невозможно выразить в C# ограничение для generic-типа, гарантирующее существование того или иного оператора. (Однако, поддержка этого [обсуждается](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/420) командой разработчиков языка.)

Однако, ваш код с вычитанием неправилен даже если `T = int`. Представьте себе, что `x == int.MaxValue`, `y == -1`, тогда `x - y` станет отрицательным из-за переполнения.

Правильно по идее так:

```
return -Math.Sign(x.CompareTo(y));
```

Comment: Приятно узнать хорошие новости. А если бы они это ещё и сделали - было бы вообще замечательно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: C#7 будет революционным, надеюсь. Вот [список обсуждаемых вещей](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/milestones/C%23%207%20and%20VB%2015).

Comment: К сожалению, под шестой тоже многое обсуждалось, и под VB.NET - тоже, но многое из обсуждаемого в итоге было отклонено. Такая судьба может и у седьмого быть...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вы, кстати, тоже можете поучаствовать в процессе обсуждения. Оно открыто для всех.